# Wrapping my head around Categories

Tags: entries, categories

I have a category group set up called 'gists'. I have entries that contain a category field which pulls in the category group 'gists'.

Now I need to access entries that are tied to individual categories but I need to do so by the category slug.

I cannot figure out how to make this happen. I have tried numerous things but cannot get my head around this. Here is my latest.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('gist').relatedTo('tech').limit(10).find() %}
```

Answer (score 3):

Craft site has the excellent document [How do I list the entries related to a category?](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/entries-related-to-category)

Building on that, you would fetch your category (by slug), and then the entries related to the category.

```
{# Fetch the category with slug 'categorySlug' #}
{% set category = craft.categories.slug('categorySlug').first() %}

{# Fetch all of the entries related to this category #}
{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(category) %}
```

Then loop over those entries.

Comment: This worked. Not sure that I understand how. But not I have something to study. Thanks

Comment: @David If you're still trying to understand how categories work I would recommend looking through the questions on [categories](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/categories) here on SE. There are some answers with very useful and basic examples.